# can you define __repr__ in a function and is a function a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, repr

If I have an function called foo:

```
def foo():
    return "foo function"
```

and if seen the fact that it returns a string without even calling the function means `__repr__` is defined like you can see in this example:

```
>>> func
<function func at 0x000001F43B1968B8>
>>> func.__repr__()
'<function func at 0x000001F43B1968B8>'
```

so now 2 questions raise to my head

1. is a function a class type?
2. if so how can I define `__repr__` from in the function

a little explanation for both questions:

1:
becuse a if you do this: `func.` and then ctrl + space in a IDE you see everything what an class also has so then I get the question is a function not a(simple) class?

2:
can I do something like this:

```
def foo():
    def __repr__():
        return "lol"
    foo.__repr__ = __repr__
    return "foo function"
```

it works in IDLE but it does not change the `__repr__` output before you call it so is that possible to change `__repr__` before the function has been called?

Comment: You're getting classes and instances mixed up. Most of the stuff you think is evidence of the function being a class is actually because the function is an instance of a class (which isn't special, because every object is an instance of a class in Python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **answeres:**

answere to question 2: no not using def

answere to question 1: yes you can see an function as a class becuse python is based around classes

> option 1(using classes):

becuse this:

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self = "foo"
```

and this:

```
class _foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = "foo"
    def __call__(self):
        return self.foo
foo = _foo()
```

are for the user the same as :

```
def foo():
    return "foo"
```

so if you really want to have something that looks like a function but with a custom version of `__repr__` you just need to make something like this:

```
class _foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = "foo"
    def __repr__(self):
        return "func(foo)"
    def __call__(self):
        return self.foo
foo = _foo()
```

becuse now if you do `foo` in IDLE after pasting this in you will see this output:

```
>>> foo
func(foo)
>>>
```

> using a wrapper class:

in this example i am using a class as wrapper:

```
class func_wrapper():
    
    def __init__(self,func,repr_msg):
        self.func = func
        self.repr_msg = repr_msg
        
        
        self = repr_msg
        
    def __call__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return self.func(*args,**kwargs)
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.repr_msg




def repr(msg):
    def dec(fn):
        
        wrapper = func_wrapper(func = fn,repr_msg = msg)
        
        return wrapper
    return dec


@repr("LOL")
def foo():
    return "foo function"

print(foo)
print(foo.__repr__())
print(foo())
```

and it this prints:

```
LOL
LOL
foo function
```

### explaining:

(almost) everything in python is an class try using type(object) you will see with almost every "object" it says it is an class.

so what I am try to say is python is almost based around classes they are everywhere becuse if you try to find a non class from something that is not a build in. Becuse only some buildin functions are not seen as classes

### recap:

so to recap my answere:

No you can't use def to have `__repr__` been called before the function has been called but you can make a class that really looks like an function and there you can make an class that for the user is just like a function

Answer (score 1):

> is a function a class type?
>   Yes

```
print(type(foo))
```

produces

```
<class 'function'>
```

> is it possible to change `__repr__` before the function has been called?

Yes, for example using a decorator:

```
from functools import wraps


def repr(msg):
    def dec(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def new_fn(*args, **kwargs):
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)

        new_fn.__repr__ = lambda: msg
        return new_fn
    return dec


@repr("LOL")
def foo():
    return "foo function"

print(foo)
print(foo.__repr__())
print(foo())
```

produces

```
<function foo at 0x7f556d959ef0>
LOL
foo function
```